# Texto a color consola Python

Tags: python, color

no se porque, no se imprimen los colores en el terminal de python, he probado en otro pc y si se imprime, pero en este no, también tengo que decir que en el otro pc si ejecuto el script fuera de visual studio tampoco me salen con colores.

```
class colors:
        HEADER = '\033[95m'
        OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
        OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
        OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
        WARNING = '\033[93m'
        FAIL = '\033[91m'
        
        BOLD = '\033[1m'
        UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
        
        ENDC = '\033[0m' #Para cerrar el color en ese print, poner siempre al final



print(colors.OKGREEN+"**New proxy added succesfully**"+ colors.ENDC)
print(colors.OKGREEN+"**Deleted proxy from the file proxyList.txt"+colors.ENDC)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No todas las terminales funcionan igual, ni tienen porqué reconocer los códigos ANSI. Te recomiendo que le eches un vistado a la librería [`rich`](https://github.com/Textualize/rich)

Comment: Usando Pycharm como IDE, los colores se muestran correctamente.

Comment: @CandidMoe Otras de las desventaja de windows es que para cambiar el color del texto debes llamar a la apis de windows o indicarle a la consola que cambie el color. En cambio en linux si funciona bien la codificacion ansi para hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

al parecer tu problema es porque estas usando la terminal de gitbash. al abrir tu terminal integrado en visual studio code, trata de seleccionar powershell o alguna de wsl, y evita cmd o gitbash para estos casos.

[image: Powershell]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la primera imagen es una captura con PowerShell, la segunda es de gitbash

Comment: Hola son dos terminales iguales de visual studio en powerShell, sigue sin ir

Answer (score 0):

Este tema es un fastidio dependiendo del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo en linux si funciona tu codigo, pero en windows al menos que uses ANSICON no te sirve. Recomiendo usar la biblioteca `colorama` que hace el trabajo por ti de conseguir el color.

```python
import colorama;
from colorama import Fore as c_fore;#Para color de texto
from colorama import Style as c_style;#Para estilo del texto, pero solo lo usaremos para reiniciar el estilo de la consola.

#Importante: tienes que iniciarlo antes de usar.
colorama.init();

print(f"{c_fore.GREEN}**New proxy added succesfully**{c_style.RESET_ALL}");
print(c_fore.GREEN+"**Deleted proxy from the file proxyList.txt"+c_style.RESET_ALL);
```

Si no lo tienes instalado solo tienes que hacer: `pip install colorama`.

> Nota: No estoy muy seguro si viene con python por defecto.

Fuentes externas:

- [How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3332860/15154709).
- [colorama.py](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).
- [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).